# Is there a way to transfer R objects to separate R sessions on linux?

Tags: r, linux, unix, process, clone

I've got a program that repeatedly loads largish datasets that are stored in R's `Rds` format.  Here's a silly example that has all of the salient features:

```
# make and save the data
big_data <- matrix(rnorm(1e6^2), 1e6)
saveRDS(big_data, file = "big_data.Rds")

# write a program that uses the data
big_data <- readRDS("big_data.Rds")
BIGGER_data <- big_data+rnorm(1)
print("hooray!")
# save this in a text file called `my_program.R`

# run this program a bunch
for (i = 1:1000){
    system("Rscript my_program.R")
}
```

The bottleneck is loading the data.  But what if I had a separate process somewhere that held the data in memory?

Maybe something like this:

```
# write a program to hold the data in memory
big_data <- readRDS("big_data.Rds")
# save this as `holder.R`  open a terminal and do
Rscript holder.R
```

Now there is a process running somewhere with my data in memory.  How can I get it from a different R session?  (I'm assuming that this would be faster than loading it -- but is this correct?)

Maybe something like this:

```
# write another program:
big_data <- get_big_data_from_holder()
BIGGER_data <- big_data+1
print("yahoo!")
# save this as `my_improved_program.R`

# now do the following:
for (i = 1:1000){
    system("Rscript my_improved_program.R")
}
```

So I guess my question is **what would the function `get_big_data_from_holder()` look like**?  Is it possible to do this?  Practical?

Backstory:  I'm trying to work around what appears to be a memory leak in R's interface to keras/tensorflow, that I've described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228475/why-does-tensorflow-keras-choke-when-i-try-to-fit-multiple-models-in-parallel/52372322#52372322).  The workaround is to let the OS clean up all of the cruft left over from a TF session, so that I can run TF sessions one after another without my computer slowing to a crawl.

Edit:  maybe I could do this with a `clone()` system call?  Conceptually I can imagine that I'd clone the process running `holder` and then run all of the commands in the program that depend on the data that's loaded.  But I don't know how this would be done.

Comment: Do you want sessions to run in parallel, or serially?

Comment: Parallel.  Would the answer differ depending?

Comment: You can run parallel R sessions that access the same memory using FORK clusters. I use the [`parallel`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) package typically. [Here](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/#Fork_or_sock)'s one website that discusses this a little bit; I'll try to find another reference as well (that was just the first that came up in my search).

Comment: Sure, yeah, I do that routinely.  But I've got a weird corner case where that doesn't work for me.  The problem isn't in forking the process that contains the data, the problem is that when the forks close, the cruft left over in memory from the forked processes isn't cleaned up.  So I went this route that calls `Rscript` in parallel

Comment: Ah, I see; sorry for the dead end.

Comment: How about creating a virtual RAM file system (e.g. using `ramfs` or `tmpfs`) then write the "file" to that

Comment: @dww great idea and googling it looks like it wouldn't be much harder to set up than mounting an ebs on aws

Answer (score 1):

You may also improve the performance of saving and loading the data by turning off compression:

```
saveRDS(..., compress = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find my `filematrix` package useful for storing and quickly accessing the big matrix.

To create it, run:

```
big_data = matrix(rnorm(1e4^2), 1e4)

library(filematrix)
fm = fm.create.from.matrix('matrix_file', big_data)
close(fm)
```

To access it from another R session:

```
library(filematrix)
fm = fm.open('matrix_file')
show(fm[1:3,1:3])
close(fm)
```

Comment: neat package!  I do need the whole thing, however.

Comment: Then use `fm.load`. It's actually rather quick.

Comment: Or use `fm.open` and access it by parts. Maybe more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks!  Will try this out tomorrow and accept if it works.